# zf url helper not creating url's as defined by the map in the passed route object

Tags: zend-framework, url, routes

I am trying to create links to switch between languages in my zf applciation. I am using the url helper to do so but if I pass a route to the helper that is comprised only of variables it does not work.

The url helper:

```
$this->url(array('lang'=>'en'),'langcontroller',false);
```

The route:

```
$router->addRoute(
            'langcontroller',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:lang/:controller',array(
                'lang' => ':lang',
                'module' => 'default',
                'controller' => ':controller',
                'action' => 'index'
            ))
    );
```

I would expect this to produce the following url: domain.com/en/current_controller
but instead I just get domain.com/en.

Do I have to get the request object, get the current controller and add it to the parameter array in the helper call? If so I don't really see the point of the helper!

The route map from the route I am passing is not followed. I assumed that the helper would create a url defined with pattern from the map of the route stated, but populated with the variables from the request object unless overridden with the cnotents of the parameter array?

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the route is defined before you try to use it in your view script or?

Comment: Sorry - should have said, yeah the route is defined in the bootstrap. I passed another route with static map parts rather than variables as a test and that worked so the route is identified but just not followed. It looks like the assemble() method in the router is just ignoring variables in the routemap. Is this expected behaviour? It's not what I expected.